# Template name not listed in Template manager?

Tags: joomla1.5, joomla-template

Hi friends i install simle template in joomla 1.5 it successfully installed but not show in list. it shows in uninstall template list to uninstall.any suggestion...?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the templateDetails.xml is missing or improperly formatted. If you are trying to uninstall the template, you can do so by deleting the folder from /templates/.